# Error: 'null' cannot be coerced to a valid version number

Tags: appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

Appium server is showing the 'null' cannot be coerced to a valid version number error.

Following are DesiredCapabilities that i have used

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, udid);
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, noReset);
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 600);
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.IOS);
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone");
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "XCUITest");
caps.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", myXcodeOrgId);
caps.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
caps.setCapability("showXcodeLog", true);
driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://" + host + ":" + port + "/wd/hub"), caps);
```

Following is the appium server log:

> ```
> Creating session with W3C capabilities: {"alwaysMatch":{"platformNa...
> [BaseDriver] Session created with session id: 77cbca4b-157d-462e-ab26-5cc9cc47c7a9
> [debug] [XCUITest] Current user: 'infotmt'
> [XCUITest] Error: 'null' cannot be coerced to a valid version number
> [XCUITest]     at coerceVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/util.js:241:11)
> [XCUITest]     at Object.coerceVersion [as compareVersions] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/util.js:268:35)
> [XCUITest]     at XCUITestDriver.compareVersions [as start] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:263:14)
> [debug] [XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
> [debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1553847186978 (13:58:06 GMT+0545 (Nepal Time))
> [debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: 'null' cannot be coerced to a valid version number
> [debug] [W3C]     at coerceVersion (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/util.js:241:11)
> [debug] [W3C]     at Object.coerceVersion [as compareVersions] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/util.js:268:35)
> [debug] [W3C]     at XCUITestDriver.compareVersions [as start] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:263:14)
> [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 29 ms - 597
> [HTTP]
> ```

I am using

```
Appium server version - 1.12.1 
Java client Version - 7.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Appium 1.12.1 the platformVersion must be set. Code to be added:

caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "12.2");

The 12.2 is the version of the iOS.

Comment: is there any way we can know the platformVersion of the app so that we do not need to add hardcoded value?

Comment: @SubanDhyako Please go through this url for platform version detection : https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-read-my-device-os-version/494/6